# Need to check for specific key presses in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I am having troubles understanding why the code below works, and I think my confusing arises with the callback to "event" in this case. I have a few images that when clicked or a corresponding keypress is logged, a sound will play. While everything works, I can't understand why the below code uses "event" instead of just using an empty function and call to "this" (ie: this.key)

I have tried to use the "this" method but it didn't work. A bit of research and I found I had to use "event" in my function.

```
function addListenerToAllDrums() {
    //store buttons in array
    var buttonArray = document.querySelectorAll(".drum");
    //iterate thru each btn
    for (var i = 0; i < buttonArray.length; i++) {
        //add a listener each iter.
        buttonArray[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
            //store html of button (ie: `w`) to variable
            var buttonInnerHTML = this.innerHTML;
            //the stored html is passed to the checkSound function
            checkSound(buttonInnerHTML); //ie: `w` = case w
        });
    }
}
```

```
//check for keypress
document.addEventListener(`keydown`, function (event) {
    //store the key in a variable
    var pressedKey = event.key
    //passes pressedKey as string (ie: `w`) to checkSound(`w`)
    checkSound(pressedKey);
});
```

```
//make a sound dependant on button press or keypress functions
function checkSound(input) {
    //Create Switch Statement based on keypress/button click input
    switch (input) {
        case `w`:
            var snare = new Audio('sounds/snare.mp3');
            snare.play();
        case `a`:
            var tom1 = new Audio('sounds/tom-1.mp3');
            tom1.play();
            break;
        case `s`:
            var tom3 = new Audio('sounds/tom-3.mp3');
            tom3.play();
            break;
        case `d`:
            var kick = new Audio('sounds/kick-bass.mp3');
            kick.play();
            break;
        case `j`:
            var tom4 = new Audio('sounds/tom-4.mp3');
            tom4.play();
            break;
        case 'k':
            var tom2 = new Audio('sounds/tom-2.mp3');
            tom2.play();
            break;
        case `l`:
            var crash = new Audio('sounds/crash.mp3');
            crash.play();
            break;


        default:
            console.log(this.innerHTML)
    }
}



addListenerToAllDrums();
```

How can my clicks work with "this" but keypresses need "event"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` refers to the object that the event is called on. For the "click" event, that's a button. For the "keydown" event that's the whole document.

So, with the click event, `this.innerHTML` gets the text on the buttons. For the document, `this.innerHTML` would get nothing, which is not what you want.

Luckily, the `event` argument for the "keydown" event stores the key that was pressed (in the `key` property), so you can get the information that way.

Comment: on a side note and for interests sake, does it store the event only as a string? for example if one of my cases happened to be ````1````, would it be stored as ````"1"```` or ````1````?

Comment: The [key property of the keydown event argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) is stored as a string, so it will always be a string, even if you push a number.

Answer (score 0):

That's because, in your case, `this` would represent the element to which the event was bound, while `event` would say what happended to the element.